# How can I use the Telegram automatic message bot when I am not there?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon, py-telegram-bot-api

how can I run the telegram auto message bot when I turn off my computer with the API I made with python?

Otherwise, it exits the terminal and the bot closes automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking why when your computer turns off, and the python file stops running, the bot no longer functions?

You would need to have either a server or another device to run it then, should you wish to turn your computer off

I'm not sure if I misunderstood this or not.

Comment: No. I just asked how I can connect to the server. Some websites were connecting to the server using google drive.